# How to change cart button "ADD" to some other name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make the "ADD" button to " ADDED" after I clicked the ADD button and make it disabled.

```
{
      products.map((val, i)=>(
        <div className="product_item">
           {
            val.productType === 'chicken'?
              <>
              <img src={img2}></img>
              <p className="product_data">Chicken Name: {val.chickeName}</p>
              <p align="left" className="product_data">weight: 500gm</p>
              <p align="left"className="product_data">₹{val.price}/- <button onClick={addTocartProduct}>ADD</button></p>
              </>: null
           }
        </div>
     ))
   }
```

I have sample project in react js having add to cart button is there. But I want to make the "ADD" button to " ADDED" after I clicked the ADD button and make it disabled.

[image]

If anyone can know please, drop your answer.

Comment: you can do this in your 'addTocartProduct' function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you have an array of `products` you should initialize an array of bool:

```
const [buttonsClicked, setButtonsClicked] = useState(new Array(products).fill(false));
```

Then

```
{
      products.map((val, i)=>(
        <div className="product_item">
           {
            val.productType === 'chicken'?
              <>
              <img src={img2}></img>
              <p className="product_data">Chicken Name: {val.chickeName}</p>
              <p align="left" className="product_data">weight: 500gm</p>
              <p align="left"className="product_data">₹{val.price}/- <button onClick={(e) => addTocartProduct(val, i)}>{buttonsClicked[i] ? 'ADDED' : 'ADD'}</button></p>
              </>: null
           }
        </div>
     ))
   }
```

And finally the `addTocartProduct` function:

```
const addTocartProduct = (val , i) => {
   let result = [...buttonsClicked];
   result[i] = !result[i];
   setButtonsClicked(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define some state in your component

```
const [ctaButton,setCtaButton] = useState('ADD')
```

Then in your `addTocartProduct` function set the state to new one

```
setCtaButton('ADDED')
```

Finally

```
<button onClick={addTocartProduct}>{ctaButton}</button>
```

Comment: There are separate buttons for each product.

Comment: Then can you share thee code of addTocartProduct

Answer (score 0):

Youjust need a simple ternary condition and a state. Here is an example :

```
const App = () => {
  const [isAdded, setIsAdded] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsAdded(true);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>{isAdded ? 'ADDED' : 'ADD'}</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```